# How to check if a number is NOT a property in a javascript object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I wanna check if a number is not a property in an object and if is not add it to the object as a property.

```
var obj{}

var arr=[1,2,3,4]
```

I´ve tried if(! number in object ) and if(! object.hasOwnProperty(number)) but didn´t work, and in both cases, I also tried to make the number become a string doing number.toString(), and nothing happened.

```
ar.forEach(number=>{
        if(!(number in obj)){   //or number.toString()

})

ar.forEach(number=>{
        if(! obj.hasOwnProperty(number)){  //or number.toString()

})
```

Comment: Do you specifically want to check if a number is not a `key` of an object or a `value` of a `key`?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] ([How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Please add `object` and `number` to the question

Comment: I want check if it is a key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code actually works once you fix the typos:

```js
var obj = {3: 'hey'}
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]

arr.forEach(number => {
        if (!(number in obj)) {
            console.log(number + ' is not in obj')
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.values(your_object) gives you an array with all the values in your object.
Then iterate trough that array and check if it contains your number.